# where i can change error message in prestashop?

Tags: web, prestashop

hei guys can you help me? I'm creating a website using the Prestashop template,
i have a problem to change error text,
I want to change the error message in the image from "Fornat tidak valid" to "nomor telpon kurang dari 11"
where can I change the error message shown in the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you looking in themes/theme-name/templates
OR
If you have access to all files to prestashop :
Search everywhere for "Fornat tidak valid"
OR
if you can find that search for the input id or form id which you can get by(in Chrome) CTRL + SHIFT + C and select the input or form get any ID related to that form and search for it in prestashop files.
Or if it is translated you can go to back office(depends on presta version) on prestashop 1.7+ go to international > Translations and select Type of translation : Themes Translation > then Language and modify
then search for ur word